# Is there any readily available implementation of Mapserver (or Geoserver)- Postgres-Openlayers combination?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, postgresql, mapserver

I am developing an web GIS for map data presentation for public.

Is there any readily available implementation of Mapserver (or Geoserver)- Postgres-Openlayers combination or similar?

### More Details:

**Overall system requirements:** Uploading, managing and publishing map
   data

**Back-end :**

- Upload geospatial data into the administration interface.  create new
  layers and organize.

**Admin should be able to:**

- Organize the mapping layers in a navigation menu
- Edit the name, legend, and
- Choose the order of the mapping layers
- Change the thematic colors of layers
- Customizable icons for map layers in the table of contents ( should
  reflect in the published map also)
- Should be able to add few attributes from the front end.

**Front-end should allow the public to:**

- Add google satellite layer.
- Zoom directly to counties from the navigation  pane.
- Turn ON/OFF layer visibility
- Turn ON/OFF layer legend
- Turn ON/OFF layer labels
- Change the layer order(up-down) in the navigation
- Export the map to PDF
- Print layout option(with or without legend, labels etc.)

Please suggest.

Comment: OpenGeo Suite feels like one Alternative.

Comment: Note, OpenGeo Suite is not referred to as Boundless, http://boundlessgeo.com/

Comment: My suggestion is that you contact one of the many open source GIS consulting companies out there and get an estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Geonode will allow you to do all if these things and is relatively easy to install and develop against.  It uses geoserver
http://geonode.org/

Answer (score 1):

I found one of the easiest to implement is the [Get SDI Portal](http://foss4g.getmap.gr/?page_id=8). You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/GeospatialEnablingTechnologies/GET-SDI-Portal)

Another one is [Mapstore](http://mapstore.geo-solutions.it/mapstore/) from Geosolutions

I think they both use the same stack i.e. Openlayers, Geoserver, Postgres and PHP

Comment: Which of these three OpenGeo Suite/Get SDI Portal/Mapstore will be suitable for the features requested?